# javascript result not showing on my input tag into forms

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
<form action="do-add-cek.php" id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Nominal</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="nominal" class="form-control" id="nominal" onkeyup="terbilang();"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Terbilang</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="terbilang" class="form-control" id="terbilang" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Rekening Tujuan</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="rekTujuan" class="form-control"  onkeyup="validAngka(this)"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Bank Tujuan</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="bankTujuan" class="form-control"  onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" />
                                        </div>
                                        <button name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                                        <button name="button_reset" type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                                    </form>
</script>
```

Comment: a little more description will be needed, if you expect us to help.

Comment: You need to give us more than that heading in order to help you.

Comment: You want to add this data to database ? or your data not `echo`ing on your `do-add-cek.php` if so post your `do-add-cek.php` code here as well. Update your question don't add an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

use [JavaScript debugging](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) to find out why your code doesn't running!
use console of your browser.

and use jQuery to add listener instead of using inline JS.

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
})// it is to see what is the value of your input

$('#nominal').on('input',function(){
  if (typeof terbilang === 'function')
    terbilang();
  debugger;
})
$('#terbilang').on('input',function(){
  if (typeof terbilang === 'function')
    terbilang();
})
$('[name="rekTujuan"]').on('input',function(){
  if (typeof validAngka === 'function')
    validAngka(this);
})
$('[name="bankTujuan"]').on('input',function(){
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="do-add-cek.php" id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<div class="form-group">
<label>Nominal</label>
<input type="text" name="nominal" class="form-control" id="nominal"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Terbilang</label>
<input type="text" name="terbilang" class="form-control" id="terbilang" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Rekening Tujuan</label>
<input type="text" name="rekTujuan" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Bank Tujuan</label>
<input type="text" name="bankTujuan" class="form-control" />
</div>
<button name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
<button name="button_reset" type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: at least some explanation, what you changed and why would be helpful. just dumping code might be sufficient for OP, but is of no help to anyone else.